# Some trouble with locking files for a longer time

Tags: c#, .net, file, locking

I have a function that is reading a file and adding some of the string in a list and returning this list. Because I wanted that nobody and nothing could change, delete or whatever the current file that I was reading I locked it. Everything was fine, I did it somehow like this:

```
public static List<string> Read(string myfile)
{
  using (FileStream fs = File.Open(myfile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
  {
    //read lines, add string to a list
    //return list
  }
}
```

Thats fine. Now I have another function in another class that is doing stuff with the list and calling other functions and so on. Now sometimes I want to move the file that I was reading. And here is the problem: because Im now in a new function and the function `Read(string myfile)` is already processed, there is no more lock in the file.

```
//in another class
public static void DoStuff(/*somefile*/)
{
  List<string> = Read(/*somefile*/);
  //the file (somefile) is not more locked!
  //do stuff

  if (something)
    Move(/*somefile*/) //could get an error, file maybe not more there or changed...
}
```

So another function/user could change the file, rename it, deleting it or whatever => Im not able to move this file. Or I will move the changed file, but I dont what that. If I would use threading, another thread with the same function could lock the file again and I could not move it.

Thats why I somehow need to lock this file for a longer time. Is there an easy way? Or do I have to replace my `using (FileStream fs = File.Open(myfile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)` code? Any suggestions? thank you

Comment: Really? you're moving the file as soon as you've read it, it's a hughly unlikely scenario you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the file locked for longer then you need to refactor your code so that the `Stream` object is kept around for longer - I would change the `Read` method to accept a `FileStream`, a little bit like this

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(myfile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess., FileShare.None))
{
    List<string> = Read(fs);
    if (something)
    {
        File.Move(/* somefile */)
    }
}
```

The problem you are going to have is that `File.Move` method is going to fail as this file is already locked (by you, but `File.Move` doesn't know that).

Depending on what exactly it is you want to do it might be possible to work out a way of keeping the file locked while also "moving" the file, (for example if you know `something` in advance you could open the file specifying [`FileOptions.DeleteOnClose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileoptions.aspx) and write a new file with the same contents in the desired destination), however this isn't really the same as moving the file and so it all depends on what exactly it is you are trying to do.

In general such things are almost always going to be more trouble than they are worth - you are better off just unlocking the file just before you move it and catching/ handling any exception that is thrown as a result of the move.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could keep it locked is to keep it exclusively open, like you have done in your code.

Maybe you need to `//do stuff` within your using statement, and then straight after call `Move`

Comment: This is something I cannot do. The other functions that are calling Read() and using //do stuff are in other classes and they have to be there. Thats why I asked about another solution.

Comment: but where do you call or trigger //do stuff from?

Comment: somewhere else in another class

Comment: Surely you must be calling it from your DoStuff method, or else how is it getting hold of  List<string>

Answer (score 0):

No amount of locking will prevent this.  A lock only protects the **data** in the file.  The user (or any other program) can still move or rename the file.  The file's attributes, including name, time stamps and file attributes are stored separately and can be changed at will.

This is just something you'll have to deal with in any Windows program.  It is rare enough that simply catching the exception is good enough to let you know that something happened to the file.  The user will rarely be surprised.  If you *really* need to know up front then you can use FileSystemWatcher to get a notification when it happens.

Comment: Answer number 10,000.  Badabing.

Answer (score 0):

You are locking the file only when Read method is called.

If you want to keep it locked and release it only when you decide, make your methods OpenFile(string filename) and CloseFile(string filename). Then remove the using statement from Read method.

Open it when you start working (lock). Read it when you need it. When you have to move it, simply create a new file with the same name and copy the content. Close the original file (unlock) and delete it.